# In Python, why re.match("^abc$", "abc\n") can match?

Tags: python

My python version is 3.11,

```py
re.match("^abc$", "abc\n")
>>> <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='abc'>
```

the output of `re.match("^abc$", "abc\n")` is not None. I am puzzled.

Added:

I want to use "^abc$" to validate form data posted.

The input is "abc\n". In this case, I need the validation fail because I only want the pure "abc" to pass the validation. But actually, the input "abc\n" can pass the validation.

I have tried in python3 and python2, but got same result

Comment: Try : `re.match("^abc$", "abc\ndef\n")` and `re.match("^abc$", "abc\ndef\n", re.MULTILINE)` and you will understand. Your example is not relevant.

Comment: [_"By default... `'$'` \[matches\] only at the end of the string **and immediately before the newline (if any) at the end of the string**."_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE)

Comment: Maybe you should add why you expected a None result in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> `$` - Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string, and in `MULTILINE` mode also matches before a newline.

Your `\n` is at the end of the string, so `$` matches just before it.